# Mysql & PHP to Excel

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, export-to-excel

I have human resource applications in my mysql table, and I'm trying to download that data as an Excel file.

```
function exportExcel($filename='ExportExcel',$columns=array(),$data=array(),$replaceDotCol=array()){
   global $connect;
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".xls");
    echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
    $count=count($columns);
    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<th>1</th>';
    echo '<th>2</th>';
    foreach($columns as $col){
        echo '<tr><th>'.trim($col).'</th>';
        foreach($data as $val){
            for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
                if(in_array($i,$replaceDotCol)){
                    echo '<td>'.str_replace('.',',',$val[$i]).'</td></tr>';
                }else{
                    echo '<td>'.$val[$i].'</td></tr>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sending two array to function, one of them contain descriptions like Name, birthday, birthplace etc. and other one is my mysql datas.

My goal is, displaying those infos in two column. In my code, output display likes only rows.

[image]

Comment: Why the HTML, I think a CSV would be easiest. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: @chris85 Unfortunately, MS Excel allows you to save HTML tables as `.xls(x)` and will properly render it per the styles given. Many novice programmers, especially from the 90's and early 2000's tended to abuse this feature to masquerade HTML tables as Excel files...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yea, I've seen that sporadically, if CSV is an option for this user though I think it would be easier. There doesn't appear to be any styling being used here (although the image has red text so maybe theres more to it).

Comment: @chris85 I didn't do any styling yet. Still stuck at html structure. After my column item ($column=array() ), it displays all of the information which comes from database ( $data=array() ).

Comment: Why do you write such code on your own? There should be libraries out there to solve this better

Answer (score 0):

you are closing your row using `</tr>` every time you write a column value. So a) your final markup is probably not valid (although Excel may tolerate it and guess what you meant) and b) that's why everything is in one column. Only close the `<tr>` when you've written all the columns you want into that row. Also you're not outputting the header row properly, it's merging into the data.

This should work:

```
echo '<tr>'; //header row

foreach($columns as $col){
    echo '<th>'.trim($col).'</th>';
}

echo '</tr>'; //end header row

foreach($data as $val){
    echo '<tr>'; //begin data row
    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
        if(in_array($i,$replaceDotCol)){
            echo '<td>'.str_replace('.',',',$val[$i]).'</td>';
        }else{
            echo '<td>'.$val[$i].'</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>'; //end data row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside html structure, also i had mistakes on my foreach loops. It seems i dont need them. Simply, using one while loop for all arrays provided proper display. Newbie here.

```
function exportExcel($filename='ExportExcel',$columns=array(),$data=array(),$replaceDotCol=array()){
   global $connect;
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".xls");
    echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM

    $count=count($columns);
    $i = 0  ;
    echo '<table border="1">';
    while ($i<=$count) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>" .$columns[$i]."</th>";
        echo "<td style='width='60%''>" .$data[$i]. "</td>";
        echo "<tr>";
        $i++;

    }
    echo "</table>";

}
```

[Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rikd.png)